# How does Apollo paginated "read" and "merge" work?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I was reading through the docs to learn pagination approaches for Apollo. This is the simple example where they explain the paginated `read` function:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api#paginated-read-functions

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        feed: {
          read(existing, { args: { offset, limit }}) {
            // A read function should always return undefined if existing is
            // undefined. Returning undefined signals that the field is
            // missing from the cache, which instructs Apollo Client to
            // fetch its value from your GraphQL server.
            return existing && existing.slice(offset, offset + limit);
          },

          // The keyArgs list and merge function are the same as above.
          keyArgs: [],
          merge(existing, incoming, { args: { offset = 0 }}) {
            const merged = existing ? existing.slice(0) : [];
            for (let i = 0; i < incoming.length; ++i) {
              merged[offset + i] = incoming[i];
            }
            return merged;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },

});
```

I have one major question around this snippet and more snippets from the docs that have the same "flaw" in my eyes, but I feel like I'm missing some piece.

Suppose I run a first query with `offset=0` and `limit=10`. The server will return 10 results based on this query and store it inside cache after accessing `merge` function.
Afterwards, I run the query with `offset=5` and `limit=10`. Based on the approach described in docs and the above code snippet, what I'm understanding is that I will get only the items from 5 through 10 instead of items from 5 to 15. Because Apollo will see that `existing` variable is present in `read` (with `existing` holding initial 10 items) and it will slice the available 5 items for me.

My question is - what am I missing? How will Apollo know to fetch new data from the server? How will new data arrive into cache after initial query? Keep in mind `keyArgs` is set to [] so the results will always be merged into a single item in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Apollo will not slice anything automatically. You have to define a merge function that keeps the data in the correct order in the cache. One approach would be to have an array with empty slots for data not yet fetched, and place incoming data in their respective index. For instance if you fetch items 30-40 out of a total of 100 your array would have 30 empty slots then your items then 60 empty slots. If you subsequently fetch items 70-80 those will be placed in their respective indexes and so on.

Your read function is where the decision on whether a network request is necessary or not will be made. If you find all the data in existing you will return them and no request to the server will be made. If any items are missing then you need to return undefined which will trigger a network request, then your merge function will be triggered once data is fetched, and finally your read function will run again only this time the data will be in the cache and it will be able to return them.

This approach is for the cache-first caching policy which is the default.

The logic for returning undefined from your read function will be implemented by you. There is no apollo magic under the hood.

If you use cache-and-network policy then a your read doesn't need to return undefined when data